# What the meaning of 'Httparty' source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

The code in `lib/httparty.rb`

```
module HTTParty
  module AllowedFormatsDeprecation
    def const_missing(const)
      if const.to_s =~ /AllowedFormats$/
        Kernel.warn("Deprecated: Use HTTParty::Parser::SupportedFormats")
        HTTParty::Parser::SupportedFormats
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end

  extend AllowedFormatsDeprecation

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.send :include, HTTParty::ModuleInheritableAttributes
    base.send(:mattr_inheritable, :default_options)
    base.send(:mattr_inheritable, :default_cookies)
    base.instance_variable_set("@default_options", {})
    base.instance_variable_set("@default_cookies", CookieHash.new)
  end

  module ClassMethods

    extend AllowedFormatsDeprecation
  ...
```

I'm wondering what is the purpose of code `extend AllowedFormatsDeprecation` in this two place?

I don't think

```
module ClassMethods

    extend AllowedFormatsDeprecation
```

it can do any sense here.

I hope a good explanation........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep study of relevant skills, I've got the point.
The first extend of `AllowedFormatsDeprecation` is to deal with this kind of const reference

```
HTTParty::AllowedFormats
```

The second extend of `AllowedFormatsDeprecation` is for the const reference in the methods of `ClassMethods`. Like

```
module ClassMethods
  def test
    AllowedFormats
  end
end
```

The `include` or `extend` of a module can not change const reference way of this module, so the method `const_missing` should defined in module.